# Fundamental polynomials: do they form a base

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, lagrange-interpolation, hamel-basis

First, is $P_n$ $n$ **or rather** $n+1$ dimensional real vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ ? Here, $n$ indicates that it should be $n$ **but** the basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n$ has $n+1$ elements, which could indicate that the dimension is after all $n+1$. In the above I was thinking as follows: by some trivial case $1$ *could* be generated from the other powers.

Finally, I understand that if $1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n$ form a base $P_n$ then
I would like to also see that the fundamental polynomials $$l_i(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)...(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})...(x-x_n)}{(x_i-x_0)...(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})...(x_i-x_n)}$$
also form a base. What are (almost) all different ways to see this fact ?

Comment: If the basis has $n+1$ elements, the dimension is $n+1$

Comment: The polynomials of degree at most $n$ form an $n+1$ dimensional space. The spanning set you wrote down is a basis.  You should [edit] the question to remove your waffling. And show us what you have tried for the real question. Can you write a proof for $n=2$?

Comment: @EthanBolker I was thinking as follows: by some trivial case $1$ *could* be generated from the other powers. I can see that you claim that it is not, but how could I prove this ? For your second question, I cannot prove it for $n=2$.

Comment: You cannot write the _function_ that's constantly $1$ as a linear combination of positive powers of $x$. To prove that, subtract $1$ and count the roots of the resulting polynomial. Write down what your "fundamental polynomials" actually are for $n=2$, perhaps for particular numerical values of the $x_i$, and try to see what they span.

Comment: @EthanBolker That's the point. I've forgotten that we are in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, say.

Comment: @EthanBolker I can see now that $l_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Does it help ? Anyway, I was asking for more than one way to see that $l_i(x)$ form a basis.

Comment: That observation is exactly what you need for a proof. I can't imagine an easier one.

Comment: @EthanBolker Right. I do not know how to use that observation to prove that $l_i(x)$ is a basis. Also I didn't mean an easier one but a bit different, just for my curiosity if another approach would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the $n+1$ polynomials $L_i$ satisfy
$$
L_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}.
$$
It follows that the only linear combination that can vanish at all the $x_j$ is the combination with all $0$ coefficients. Therefore the $L_i$ are independent. Since there are $n+1$ of them in a space of that dimension they form a basis.

Comment: @ApassJack I will leave your edit, but there really is no need to replace "the $0$ polynomial" with the wordier "the combination with all $0$ coefficients".